# I can't login to LUIS Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-language-understanding

I can't login to Luis via https://eu.luis.ai/home. Previously, when I logged in with a different personal account, I was able to login to Luis and to build my model(s). However, my organization just made a corporate account and I am not able to login with the newly created account.

I simply end up in a loop where I am requested to provide my username and password, then they forward me to the default Luis homepage and then I have to provide my username and password again if I click on the 'log in' button.

Different browsers didn't work. I am always able to continue on my personal account. Is it perhaps a security issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding log files, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Could you add message you are receiving? Could you eventually append some screenshot? Where do you see the difference between successful login with personal account and unsuccessful login with corporate account?

Comment: luis.ai uses a login system that may redirect you to your company's login page. If you're experiencing issues then I recommend asking your coworkers if they have any experience with login issues. Although I can see you've tried multiple browsers, it may still be a good idea to try clearing your browsing data.

Comment: @CKE I don't get any errors so neither can I add log files. I'm just simply trying to log in but I get looped back to the home page of Luis.

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid I don't receive any messages. I could append some screenshots but I am a beginner on StackOverflow and don't know how. I can see that I have succesfully logged in with my personal account since I end up in the Luis environment where I can select my app, add intents etc

Comment: @KyleDelaney my coworkers experience the same. I have tried clearing my browsing data but I still face a loop.

Comment: @Ted - In order to further troubleshoot your issue, I will need to see a HAR file that contains sensitive information that should be sent privately rather than posted publicly. Please email me

Comment: @Ted - Please let me know if you intend to email me or not

Comment: @KyleDelaney thank you for answering me, I have found the solution. Microsoft didn't send me an error code but when inspecting the page source, I stumbled upon the following: "AADSTS65005: Using application 'Europe.Luis.ai' is currently not supported for your organization XXXXX.com because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of XXXXX.com before the application Europe.Luis.ai can be provisioned". The issue is solved by connecting the domain to Azure. Only question remains is why Microsoft doesn't submit this error visually.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is solved by connecting the specified (company) domain to Azure. This applies specifically if you work with different directories.

I solved the issue when I stumbled upon the following error code when inspecting the webpage source: "AADSTS65005: Using application 'Europe.Luis.ai' is currently not supported for your organization XXXXX.com because it is in an unmanaged state. An administrator needs to claim ownership of the company by DNS validation of XXXXX.com before the application Europe.Luis.ai can be provisioned".

Comment: can you please elaborate the answer?